# Accessing a button control of a page from another class Windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

The problem I'm facing is that, I'm unable to access a control(button) which is in the MenuPanoramaPage.xaml from another page which is MyProfile.xaml.

I wanted to change the content within the button when I select the radio button which is in the MyProfile.xaml. How could I make this?

I tried using this within the button tag in xaml:

```
x:FieldModifier="public"
```

But it didn't work out. How can I work on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use MVVM Pattern in which use can handle these kind of problems like handling data of one page from other page.
I give you a simple scenario :-

Suppose you want to change the content of a button that is on another page then what you have done basically is.

**Some Points** :-

**1**- > Define a string property in viewmodel of the page that contain button. and bind this property to the content property of the button.

**2** -> So suppose you want to change it from other page then all you have to do is send a message from another page to change this property. And it will be automatically updated on button(you will get it after some example setup).

**3** -> It is not related to some simple string contents. You handle whole data that will be displayed on that page and other View related properties too.(Basically MVVM is much more powerful than you can thought of).

**4** -> Last point If you want to make a quality Windows Phone app then MVVM pattern is a good fit.

**Links** :-

[How to implement MVVM in Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521153%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[**Basic one from Channel9**](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/A-very-simple-implementation-sample-of-MVVM-for-the-Windows-Phone)

[**What actually MVVM is ?**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh848246.aspx)

Explore those. You will not regret. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is not possible. You only have direct access to the controls on the page you are on. In this case you can only change the controls in MyProfile.xaml.

But what you could do is sending an event or message (if you are using mvvm) to the MenuPanoramaPage.xaml / ViewModel.